# How to exclude transitive dependency from bower

Tags: bower

I'm using bower 1.2.6 and let's say I have 2 dependencies:

```
A#1.0.0
B#0.2.0
 |- A >=0.5.0 <1.0.0
```

With that configuration bower fails saying it's unable to find a suitable version for A.

Is there a way to exclude the transitive dependencies for B, as I know it will work with A#1.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found we can add the `resolutions`option to the `bower.json` file:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "A": "~1.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Could you mention where this is documented?

Comment: Here's the official documentat (https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#resolutions), but it's not so much documented as it is a part of the Bower (http://jaketrent.com/post/bower-resolutions/). It also has some potential problems (https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/532)